# My setState method called multiple times which causes a problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a weird problem, I readed some answers about it and some solutions but still can not manage to solve mine, that is my problem, which is well known, ( lot of code I know ) :

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly 
calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits 
the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

This is my component :

```
class Operations extends Component {
state = {
    data: [],
    mode: 1, // 1 desktop - 2 phone - 3 bigdesktop - 4 tablette
    contratSelected: 0
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ data: !isEmpty(this.props.operations) ? this.props.operations : "" });


// 
//         Many other methods here, but not needed to show the problem
// 

sortDateOperation = ({ order }) => {
    const data = partition(this.state.data, item => !item.isChild);

    for (let counter = 0; counter < data[0].length; counter += 1) {
        data[0][counter].chiffrage = this.dateToNumber(data[0][counter].dateOperation);
    }

    const result = orderBy(
        data[0],
        ["annee", "chiffrage"],
        ["desc", order === 1 ? "asc" : "desc"]
    );

    result.forEach((res, index) => {
        res.id = index;
    });

    // The Line causing error
    this.setState({ data: result });

    return result;
};

render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Title text={this.props.title || ""} color="primary" />
            {this.state.mode !== 2 && (
                <div className="co-table-data">
                    <div className="co-data-table">
                        <Grid container>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                                <Datatable
                                    value={this.state.data}
                                    type="grey"
                                    autoLayout
                                    upperCaseHeader
                                    rowGroupHeaderTemplate={data => data.annee}
                                    rowGroupFooterTemplate={() => undefined}
                                    rowGroupMode="subheader"
                                    groupField="annee"
                                    className="co-operations-contrat"
                                >
                                    <Column
                                        header={intl.get("CONTRAT_DATE_DE_VALEUR")}
                                        field="dateOperation"
                                        sortable="custom"
                                        sortFunction={this.sortDateOperation}
                                        body={this.getDateContent}
                                    />
                                    <Column
                                        header={intl.get("CONTRAT_TYPE_MOUVEMENT")}
                                        field="typeMouvement"
                                        body={this.getTypeContent}
                                    />
                                    <Column
                                        header={`${intl.get("MONTANT")}(€)`}
                                        field="montantOperation"
                                        sortable="custom"
                                        sortFunction={this.sortMontanta}
                                        body={this.getMontantContent}
                                    />
                                </Datatable>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12} />
                        </Grid>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}

            {this.state.mode === 2 && <MobileDatatable />}
        </Fragment>
    );
}
}

export default Operations;
```

So when I click on my Columln is the datatable, my dates get sorted, I need to update my state ( data ) but I get this error, here exactly :

```
....
<Column
                                        header={intl.get("CONTRAT_DATE_DE_VALEUR")}
                                        field="dateOperation"
                                        sortable="custom"
                                        sortFunction={this.sortDateOperation}
                                        body={this.getDateContent}
                                    />

....
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

problem is in your Column componet's header prop

```
 header={intl.get("CONTRAT_DATE_DE_VALEUR")}
```

should be this

```
header={() => {intl.get("CONTRAT_DATE_DE_VALEUR")}}
```

you can't execute function directly inside component react will automatically call for you

so, change all three Column component's header property to this

```
header={() => {intl.get("CONTRAT_DATE_DE_VALEUR")}}
```

```
 header={() => {intl.get("CONTRAT_TYPE_MOUVEMENT")}}
```

```
header={() => {`${intl.get("MONTANT")}(€)`}}
```

Comment: I did, It did not work at all, same thing, one problem added is I am not getting my labels :D because intl.get("") return a label :) .. Thatnk yo for your time

Comment: may be ` header={() => {`${intl.get("MONTANT")}(€)`}} ` should be this ` header={() =>  return`${intl.get("MONTANT")}(€)`} `